# Express- alternative redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I was wondering if theres a methode in Express to load a specific page for the user without redirecting the user to the html file.

So instead of `res.redirect("https://mywebsite.com/subsite");`

maybe theres another method implemented to load the subsite „ subsite.html“ that does not fire the

```
app.get(/\/subsite(?:\.html)?$/, function(){});
```

event.

So I want to catch all calls to `/subsite` and `/subsite.html` check if the **browser/client** is **allowed** to enter the site. If all is correct I will let the browser enter the site otherwise I want to implement a redirect.

What I got so far:

```
app.get(/\/subsite(?:\.html)?$/, function(req, res) {
  let isValid = checkIfUserIsValid() /* my own logic */
  if (isValid) {
   //how to load subsite.html on the client?
  } else res.redirect("https://mywebsite.com/subsite");
});
```

Note: I need a method cause I‘m stuck in a redirection loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand what you're trying to do? So currently when someone loads www.siteA.com/xx you actually want to load www.siteB.com/xx but without redirecting them to it? But then that is redirecting to you? Otherwise, if it's the same site surely you could just use `res.render` and render whatever view you want from your router

Comment: `cause I'm stuck in a redirect loop` ... how?

Comment: Then check if the user has access Before responding with the sites html code. If the user does not have access, send a 401 Unauthorized or a 403 Forbidden response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get(“/xx“, (req, res) => {
    let permissionsOk = // check your user's permissions
    if (permissionsOk) {
        res.send(/* regular page html */);
    } else {
        res.send(/* access denied html */);
    }
});
```

The idea is that you can have conditional response and serve different html on the same route according to some internal logic

Comment: Will not prevent the user from entering `/xx.html` as I've mentioned.

Comment: Then you can either have two separate routes for /xx and /xx.html, or use a reglar expression in a route so it will catch both /xx and /xx.html. Express allows it. Besides, there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. I've already implemented regex. But this does not avoid a infinite loop.

Comment: Is `subsite.html` a static file? If so, you can do

  if (isValid) {
      res.sendFile('/subsite.html');
  } else res.redirect("https://mywebsite.com/subsite");